# Evaluation of an exotic integral

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, pi

How can I prove the following:
$$ \int _0^1\:\frac{\sin \left(\pi x\right)}{x^x\left(1-x\right)^{1-x}}dx=\frac{\pi }{e} $$
I'd start by taking the imaginary part of:
$$ \int _0^1\:\frac{\exp\left(\pi x i\right)}{x^x\left(1-x\right)^{1-x}}dx $$
But I don't know where to go from there? How can I use complex analysis to evaluate this integral?

Comment: i would rather try with substitution first

Comment: It has a solution [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/324647/integrate-int-01x-x1-xx-1-sin-pi-xdx).